# Python class decorator and maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, class, decorator

I try define class decorator. I have problem with `__init__` method in decorated class. If `__init__` method invokes `super` the `RuntimeError` *maximum recursion depth exceeded* is raised.

Code example:

```
def decorate(cls):
    class NewClass(cls): pass
    return NewClass

@decorate
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Michał

**Edit 1**

Thanks to Mike Boers answer I realized that correct question is what should I do to achive that super(Foo, self) point to proper class.

I have also two limitation. I want invoke `Foo.__init__` method and I can't change `Foo` class definition.

**Edit 2**

I have solved this problem. I modify decorator function body. I don't return new class. Instead of I wrap methods of orginal class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class Decorators, Inheritance, super(), and maximum recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542747/class-decorators-inheritance-super-and-maximum-recursion)

Comment: How are you able to apply a decorator to the Foo class but you cannot change it's definition?

Comment: I'm writting ajax validation django app. It should be generic and does not require changes in form class definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `NewClass.__init__` to prevent recursion, because `NewClass.__init__` is `Foo.__init__` and it keeps calling itself.

```
def decorate(cls):
    class NewClass(cls):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    return NewClass
```

---

New idea:

How about not subclassing it? Maybe monkey patching is your friend?

```
def decorate(cls):
    old_do_something = cls.do_something
    def new_do_something(self):
        print "decorated",
        old_do_something(self)

    cls.do_something = new_do_something
    return cls

@decorate
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_something(self):
        print "Foo"

f = Foo()
f.do_something()
```

Comment: Ok, but I want execute Foo.__init__ method. I also can't  edit Foo class definition.

Comment: Wish "not subclass" was a separate answer so I could +1 it above modifying the actual class (which doesn't work in too many cases).

Answer (score 5):

Remember that a decorator is simply syntactic sugar for:

```
>>> Foo = decorate(Foo)
```

So in this case the name Foo actually refers to the `NewClass` class. Within the `Foo.__init__` method you are in fact asking for the super `__init__` of `NewClass`, which is `Foo.__init__` (which is what is currently running).

Thus, your `Foo.__init__` keeps receiving its own `__init__` to call, and you end up in an infinite recursion.