# TypeError when using super method with class decorator for a derived class

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Firstly, apologies for the long explanation.

### Version #1 - Code: Class decorator for a Class

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, klass):
        print "A::__init__()"
        self._klass = klass

    def __call__(self):
        print "A::__call__()"
        return self._klass()

    def __del__(self):
        print "A::__del__()"

@A
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B::__init__()"

def main():
    b = B()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Version #1 - Output:

```
A::__init__()
A::__call__()
B::__init__()
A::__del__()
```

### Version #2 - Code: Class decorator for a Derived Class which explicitly initialises the Base Classes.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, klass):
        print "A::__init__()"
        self._klass = klass

    def __call__(self):
        print "A::__call__()"
        return self._klass()

    def __del__(self):
        print "A::__del__()"

class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Parent1:: __init__()"
        super(Parent1, self).__init__()

class Parent2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Parent2:: __init__()"
        super(Parent2, self).__init__()    

@A
class B(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B::__init__()"
#        super(B, self).__init__()
        Parent1.__init__(self)
        Parent2.__init__(self)

def main():
    b = B()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Version #2 - Output:

```
A::__init__()
A::__call__()
B::__init__()
Parent1:: __init__()
Parent2:: __init__()
Parent2:: __init__()
A::__del__()
```

### Version #3 - Code: Class decorator for a Derived Class with `super()`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, klass):
        print "A::__init__()"
        self._klass = klass

    def __call__(self):
        print "A::__call__()"
        return self._klass()

    def __del__(self):
        print "A::__del__()"   

class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Parent1:: __init__()"
        super(Parent1, self).__init__()

class Parent2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Parent2:: __init__()"
        super(Parent2, self).__init__()

@A
class B(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B::__init__()"
        super(B, self).__init__()

def main():
    b = B()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### Version #3 - Output:

```
A::__init__()
A::__call__()
B::__init__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "so.py", line 36, in main
    b = B()
  File "so.py", line 10, in __call__
    return self._klass()
  File "so.py", line 32, in __init__
    super(B, self).__init__()
TypeError: must be type, not A
A::__del__()
```

### Question:

Version #1 is just for a reference. It explains what I am trying to do i.e. capture the `creation` and `deletion` of objects of `class B`.

In version #2, I have tried the same for objects of a `class B` which is derived from `Parent1` and `Parent2` which are initialised explicitly using `Parent1.__init__(self)` and `Parent2.__init__(self)` which works fine as expected.

But in version #3, I have tried the same with `super()` method. But I get the following error - `TypeError: must be type, not A`. I think this is because the `__init__()` method for all the parent classes in the `MRO` chain is not properly called - Why? And, how do I fix this?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2543256/705086 it's by Alex Martelli, you can trust that guy! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took sometime to understand why it is hard to capture the object instantiation and object deletion using `__call__` and `__del__` methods respectively. The following are some of the useful references

- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/
- [I don't understand this python __del__ behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104535/i-dont-understand-this-python-del-behaviour)
- the same topic has also been discussed in the python-list mailer - check out the thread here - https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2014-February/667592.html

There are excellent hacks available to do this using `__del__` method but they are have side effects! For example, the answer given by @user2357112 is a good hack but it does not work when we make a circular reference because the garbage collector cannot determine which `__del__` among the circular reference to call first! However this can be avoided by using a weak ref; but its still a hack!

One of the suggestions that was made was to create a context manager which can create and delete the objects of a particular class.

I have the following example which sort of emulates that. Please take a closer look at the `Controller` decorator.

```
class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #print "Parent1::__init__()"
        super(Parent1, self).__init__()

class Parent2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #print "Parent2::__init__()"
        super(Parent2, self).__init__()

def Controller(_cls):
    class Wrapper(_cls):
        def create(self, name):
            ret = _cls.create(self, name)
            print "Added to Database! :: ", name
            # Database add here!
            return ret

        def remove(self, name):
            ret = _cls.remove(self, name)
            print "Deleted from Database! :: ", name
            # Database delete here!
            return ret
    return Wrapper

@Controller
class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #print "Manager::__init__()"
        self._repo = []

    def create(self, name):
        a = A(name)
        print "Object created :: ", name
        self._repo.append(a)

    def remove(self, name):
        for i, item in enumerate(self._repo):
            if item._name == name:
                del self._repo[i]
                print "Object removed :: ", name

    def display(self):
        for item in self._repo:
            print item

class A(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self, name):
        #print "A::__init__()"
        self._name = name
        super(A, self).__init__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._name

def main():
    m1 = Manager()
    m1.create("apples")
    m1.create("oranges")
    m1.create("grapes")
    #m1.display()
    m1.remove("apples")
    #m1.display()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When executed, it produces the following result:

```
Object created ::  apples
Added to Database! ::  apples
Object created ::  oranges
Added to Database! ::  oranges
Object created ::  grapes
Added to Database! ::  grapes
Object removed ::  apples
Deleted from Database! ::  apples
```

This is the safest solution that I could come up for my problem. Suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 6):

The main problem is that `super`'s first argument needs to be the actual class, but in version 3, in

```
super(B, self)
```

`B` isn't the class you created. It's the `A` instance wrapping the class. You would need to do something like

```
class _B(Parent1, Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B::__init__()"
        super(_B, self).__init__()
B = A(_B)
```

or instead of wrapping `B` in an `A` instance, use a decorator that replaces `B`'s `__init__` and `__del__` methods with wrappers without replacing the whole `B` class.

Also, if you want to track the deletion of `B` instances, a `__del__` method on `A` won't do that. It'll track the deletion of the class, not individual instances.

---

Here's a decorator that should do what you want, without the many problems that come from wrapping the class in something that isn't a class:

```
def track_creation_and_deletion(klass):
    original_init = klass.__init__
    try:
        original_del = klass.__del__
    except AttributeError:
        def original_del(self):
            pass

    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print '{}.{}.__init__'.format(klass.__module__, klass.__name__)
        return original_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def new_del(self):
        print '{}.{}.__del__'.format(klass.__module__, klass.__name__)
        return original_del(self)

    # functools.wraps doesn't play nicely with built-in methods,
    # so we handle it ourselves
    new_init.__name__ = '__init__'
    new_init.__doc__ = original_init.__doc__
    new_init.__module__ = klass.__module__
    new_init.__dict__.update(getattr(original_init, '__dict__', {}))

    new_del.__name__ = '__del__'
    new_del.__doc__ = original_del.__doc__
    new_del.__module__ = klass.__module__
    new_del.__dict__.update(getattr(original_del, '__dict__', {}))

    klass.__init__ = new_init
    klass.__del__ = new_del

    return klass
```

About half of this is error-handling and copying some metadata to make the new methods look like they were defined by the caller. The key parts are that we define new `__init__` and `__del__` methods wrapping and replacing the class's old ones. When an instance of the decorated class is created, the `__init__` method we gave it will invoke logging code of our choice. When an instance of the decorated class is garbage collected, the `__del__` method we gave it will invoke other logging code. Since we didn't replace the class object itself, references to the class by name in `super` calls will refer to the class they need to refer to.

One limitation of this approach is that it's difficult to inspect the instance itself in our `__init__`, because it may not be fully constructed, even after the wrapped `__init__` returns. For example, if we try to `print` the instance, we may trigger a subclass's `__str__` method relying on subclass attributes that aren't ready yet, causing an AttributeError.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of passing `self._klass` to the `__init__` call: `self._klass(self._klass)`, and then use that in `super` call instead of `B`. But, this looks better.